# How can add unique name to image android

Tags: android

I try to add unique name as a number to image when I upload image to server and folder to save it .
I need use just number and that number not duplicates. I looked for different ways to do this but I did not succeed.Now if I upload the image, the name will be the same as the previous one, and this makes the previous image deleted from the folder.
If anyone know the solution please help me.

I use this code:

```
    private void upload() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, upload_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                            Toast.makeText(Add.this, Response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                if (bitmap != null)
                {
                    params.put("image", imageToString(bitmap));
                    params.put("webformatURL", img_location + "/" + textfrom.getText().toString().trim() + ".jpg");

                }

                params.put("FROM", textfrom.getText().toString().trim());



                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = (RequestQueue) Volley.newRequestQueue(Add.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

and php file

```
 <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "localhost";
    $password = "localhost";
    $dbname = "localhost";


    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn) {



        $image = $_POST["image"];
        $webformatURL = $_POST["webformatURL"];
        $FROM = $_POST["FROM"];
$date = date('Y-m-d');


        $sql = "insert into image(FROM,webformatURL) values('$FROM','$webformatURL')";
        $upload_path = "uploads/$FROM.jpg";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        {
            file_put_contents($upload_path, base64_decode($image));
            echo json_encode(array('response' => 'Image Upload Successfully'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('response' => 'Image Upload Failed'));
        }

    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('response' => 'Connection Error'));
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: get date in miliseconds

Comment: when I try get date it come with name of days in database but in folder just date view so that make photo now view in my app in recycleriew

Comment: For this reason I only want to add numbers

Comment: data as timestamp  just includes numbers.

Comment: @Dharman I didn't understand you very much, brother. I am a new application developer

Comment: Your PHP is really bad. You need to learn how to write PHP properly and do not use the code you have written. There are some good articles here: https://phpdelusions.net/

Comment: @Dharman I got it, thank you brother for the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am naming like below

```
String fileName = String.format(Locale.US, "%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

easy and practical.

Comment: Where can I apply this in my code? Sorry, I am a new application developer with little experience

Comment: @marwan where you gonna set unique name for a file or image.

Comment: I will try it and tell you

Comment: Can this number be repeated after a some of time?